How can I configure wait4x in docker-compose to wait until QuestDB starts?
I'm trying to use QuestDB in a Docker environment.
I use wait4x https://github.com/atkrad/wait4x to ensure that database is ready (ie database container running and database "ready" for ingesting data) before running a service called "MYSERVER-api" which will ingest data to DB.
A typical docker-compose.yml looks like
services:
  timescaledb:
    image: questdb/questdb
    container_name: questdb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - MYSERVER_DBNAME=${MYSERVER_DBNAME}

  wait-for-pg:
    image: atkrad/wait4x
    depends_on:
      - timescaledb
    command: postgresql 'postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@timescaledb:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable' --timeout 90s --interval 250ms

  MYSERVER-api:
    build: 
      context: MYSERVER-api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      wait-for-pg:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    volumes:
      - ./MYSERVER-api/config:/home/${USER}/config

I tried the above configuration but wait4x never proceeds.
How can I use configure to wait until QuestDB starts up?
